# Symfony 2 : Form on an object, not a mapped Entity

Tags: forms, symfony, object, entity

I'm trying to map my formType on a custom object, which is not persisted or anything..

So I set the `data_class`, but I get the following error :

> Class "CDA\SvBundle\Lib\ImportContact\Contact" seems not to be a managed Doctrine
>   entity. Did you forget to map it?

So no I didn't forget to map it, that was on purpose...

Here is the type I'm using

```
class ImportContactType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('contacts', 'entity', array('class' => "CDA\SvBundle\Lib\ImportContact\Contact"));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'importContact';
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CDA\SvBundle\Lib\ImportContact\ImportContact',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full declaration of your type ?

Comment: Here are my formType and the two custom objects : http://paste.laravel.fr/#/show/oxE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entity` FormType is a Doctrine FormType that needs an entity as a `class` (it loads value from ORM). You should use a `choice` type instead.

So the problem does not come from data_class but from the `contacts` form field.

**edit**: Error message mentions Contact, not ImportContact, does it ?

Comment: That's what I was expecting ..! But what is the best way to use my Entites as choices ? Should I use the Options of `buildForm` ?

Comment: Use the option 'choice_list' of choice FormType and populate it with your entities.

Comment: I meant, what is the best practice to pass it to the formType : in the constructor, adding an option, or..?

Comment: Pass to the __construct, set a class variable, use it in buildForm. Maybe not the best way, but clear and functionnal.

Comment: So that's what I've done, but then how to check if the form is valid ?
Because, in the action where the form posts to, it doesn't have the elements to retrieve the contact objects (they are retrieved using google oauth API), so I can't pass it to the constructor.. So my form isn't valid because there is no "choice_list" defined.

That's why I was looking for the same kind of field as "entity", something which could recognize if the data sent are valid or not, based on a php object..

Comment: You should ask another question for that and post your Controller code. You must load your form at display and at submission.